# Why is there space under my image?

Tags: html, css

Notice in the following screenshot, there is a white space under image:
[image]

I don't understand why there is this gap, how do I remove it. The page is live at http://goo.gl/Kf8FV5

Markup:

```
<section id="pricing-table">
<table width="950" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="190" height="10">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="760" height="10" colspan="4" align="left" valign="top"><img src="images/membership-plans-design_03.png" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="middle" class="featurehead">Heading</td>
<td colspan="4" class="featureset"><table width="760" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="middle" class="featurehead">Heading</td>
<td colspan="4" class="featureset"><table width="760" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="middle" class="featurehead">Heading</td>
<td colspan="4" class="featureset"><table width="760" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="middle" class="featurehead">Heading</td>
<td colspan="4" class="featureset"><table width="760" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="middle" class="featurehead">Heading</td>
<td colspan="4" class="featureset"><table width="760" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="middle" class="featurehead">Heading</td>
<td colspan="4" class="featureset"><table width="760" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="middle" class="featurehead">Heading</td>
<td colspan="4" class="featureset"><table width="760" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="middle" class="featurehead">Heading</td>
<td colspan="4" class="featureset"><table width="760" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
<td width="190" height="42" align="center" valign="middle">Feature</td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><img src="images/membership-plans-design_08.png" alt=""></td>
<td><img src="images/membership-plans-design_09.png" alt=""></td>
<td><img src="images/membership-plans-design_10.png" alt=""></td>
<td><img src="images/membership-plans-design_11.png" alt=""></td>
</tr>
</table>
</section>
```

Css:

```
#pricing-table { margin: 0 auto; width: 950px; text-align: center;}
.featureset {
background-image: url(images/membership-plans-design_05.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 42px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
color:#FFF;
}
.featurehead {
background-color:#CCC;
font-weight: bold;
border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5804278/1612146

Comment: Your HTML markup is a complete mess. You are missing `</tr>` tags and you seem to have a table within a `<td>` you are always going to have problems with the layout. Consider using `<div>` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Images are inline elements, so they have a white space after them (like a `<span>` element). To remove that white space, change them to block elements like this :

```
img{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `<img src="images/membership-plans-design_03.png" alt="">` to

```
<img src="images/membership-plans-design_03.png" alt="" style="display: block;">
```

And to be more precise images are an `inline-block` element.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS,

```
section#pricing-table td img{
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<img>` is an `inline-block` element by default. You can remove the white space around it by setting it's parent's `font-size` to zero, or by changing it's `display` property.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/xPFRm/)